# How to enumerate Directories created in IsolatedStorage for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

Say I have created many directories in IsolatedStorage. I wan to enumerate and display them in a listBox so that I can choose. Example :

### Directories

Restuarants
Hotels
ShoppingMall
....

The problem I want to solve:

The ListBox will contain these. If I click Restuarant, it will get all the files stored in this directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IsolatedStorageFile.GetDirectoryNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190297%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to enumerate directories.

```
private string[] GetLocationTypes()
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        return store.GetDirectoryNames();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank u. But how do I bind this string[] to ListBox so that it shows all the directory-name? Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle: That's a pretty separate question, and one which is likely to be pretty easy to find an answer to in any WP7 Silverlight tutorial. Binding collections is pretty easy in Silverlight.

Comment: @MilkBottle: I have to agree with @Jon, your second question implies you need to spent more time looking at basic WP7 samples to get a better idea of what is required to make applications. The default "Data Bound" project template, for example, provides a data bound list box.

Comment: @Both: Thank u all. I wasnt sure on the XAML level. In Code behind I think LBox.ItemSource = GetLocationTypes() , this will do. On Xaml for ListBox, I need {Binding ?} for DataTemplate  of ListBox. Yes, your solution work. I will search for the 2nd part.